# Where can i download the src jar for playframework

Tags: playframework

Sorry, I just don't know where to get this src from. I'm not familiar with github at all - is there a button that makes a src jar for me to download?

Comment: Can be closed under the official close reason: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam._

Answer (score 1):

**SBT**

Downloading of the source jar, as well as Javadoc, can be forced by `withSources()` and `withJavadoc()` definitions, like

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.15" withSources() withJavadoc())
```

The more information in the documentation: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html#Download+Sources

**Eclipse**

The eclipse plugin can be forced to download all source files by specifying `with-source` flag:

```
[my-first-app] $ eclipse with-source=true
```

More information here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/IDE#Generate-configuration

**GitHub repository**

You can always download the source from the GitHub repository, but it will not be the jar file.

[image]